insert in 2 tables dependent on one and another but the data in 2nd table is dependent on the first table response in drizzle ORM
The Error ->
 ⨯ PostgresError: insert or update on table "godly-test_characters" violates foreign key constraint "godly-test_characters_anime_id_godly-test_anime_id_fk"
    at ErrorResponse (P:\godly-test\.next\server\chunks\ssr\node_modules_postgres_src_b9a524._.js:1255:171)
    at handle (P:\godly-test\.next\server\chunks\ssr\node_modules_postgres_src_b9a524._.js:1055:728)
    at Socket.data (P:\godly-test\.next\server\chunks\ssr\node_modules_postgres_src_b9a524._.js:943:17)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:519:28)
digest: "1545992261"

I am trying to insert actors and characters into database like this
async function fetchAnimeInfo(animeId: number) {
  const animeStringId = animeId.toString();

  const getAnime = await db.query.animeTable.findFirst({
    where: (animeTable, { eq }) => eq(animeTable.id, animeId),
    with: {
      characters: {
        with: {
          voicedActor: true,
        },
      },
    },
  });

  if (!getAnime) {
    const animeInfo = await anilist.fetchAnilistInfoById(animeStringId);

    const characters = animeInfo.characters as AnimeCharacter[];

    const chars = await Promise.all(
      characters.map(async (char) => {
        const charName = typeof char.name === "string" ? char.name : char.name.full;

        const actor = char.voiceActors.filter(
          (act) => act.language?.toLocaleUpperCase() === "JAPANESE",
        )?.[0];

        if (actor) {
          const actorName = typeof actor.name === "string" ? actor.name : actor.name.full;

          const [actorId] = await db
            .insert(actorsTable)
            .values({
              id: actor.id,
              name: actorName,
              voiceCharacter: char.id,
            })
            .returning({ id: actorsTable.id });

          const [charId] = await db
            .insert(charactersTable)
            .values({
              id: char.id,
              name: charName,
              anime: animeId,
              voicedActor: actorId?.id,
            })
            .returning({ id: charactersTable.id });

          return charId?.id;
        }

        return null;
      }),
    );
    const newChars = chars.filter(
      (char) => typeof char !== "undefined" && char !== null,
    );

    if (newChars.length > 0) {
      // const anime = await db.insert({ animeTable }).values....
    }
    return animeInfo;
  }
  }
}

I am fetching data from anilist and it gives me data like this
[
{
id: number;
characters: {
  id: number;
  role?: string;
  name: {
  first: string;
  last: string;
  full: string;
  native?: string;
  userPreferred?: string;
};
  image?: string;
  voiceActors: {
  id: number;
  language?: string;
  name: {
  first: string;
  last: string;
  full: string;
  native?: string;
  userPreferred?: string;
};
  image?: string;
};
}
...
}
]

The schemas are
// actors.ts
import { integer, text } from "drizzle-orm/pg-core";
import createTable from "./createTable";
import { relations } from "drizzle-orm";
import { animeTable } from "./anime";
import { charactersTable } from "./characters";

export const actorsTable = createTable("actors", {
  id: integer("id").primaryKey().unique(),
  name: text("name"),
  voiceCharacter: integer("voice_character"),
});

export const actorsRelations = relations(actorsTable, ({ one, many }) => ({
  voiceCharacter: one(charactersTable, {
    fields: [actorsTable.voiceCharacter],
    references: [charactersTable.id],
  }),
  anime: many(animeTable),
}));

// characters.ts
import { integer, text } from "drizzle-orm/pg-core";
import createTable from "./createTable";
import { relations } from "drizzle-orm";
import { actorsTable } from "./actors";
import { animeTable } from "./anime";

export const charactersTable = createTable("characters", {
  id: integer("id").primaryKey().unique(),
  name: text("name"),
  voicedActor: integer("voiced_actor").references(() => actorsTable.id),
  anime: integer("anime_id"),
});

export const charactersRelations = relations(
  charactersTable,
  ({ one, many }) => ({
    anime: one(animeTable, {
      fields: [charactersTable.anime],
      references: [animeTable.id],
    }),
    voicedActor: many(actorsTable),
  }),
);

// anime.ts
import { integer, text } from "drizzle-orm/pg-core";
import createTable from "./createTable";
import { relations } from "drizzle-orm";
import { charactersTable } from "./characters";

export const animeTable = createTable("anime", {
  id: integer("id").primaryKey().unique(),
  title: text("title"),
  characters: integer("characters_id").references(() => charactersTable.id),
});

export const animeRelations = relations(animeTable, ({ many }) => ({
  characters: many(charactersTable),
}));

I tried Following official docs can't find anything useful.There is no type error.Everything seems to be ok but it doesn't work.
Don't Know What I am doing wrong. Please Help!
